# Entity to bean with cyclic reference in JAVA

Tags: java, jpa, entity, apache-commons-beanutils

I have three entities, EntityA, EntityB and EntityC, in such a way that

- EntityA has a @OneToMany relationship with EntityB
- EntityC has a @OneToMany relationship with EntityB

  -> EntityB has one @ManyToOne relationship with EntityA and EntityC.

  **A <=> B <=> C**

I have a GET REST service, which given an EntityA ID returns a bean (BeanA)  which represents the EntityA java object. The response is generated from the BeanA java object, and it produce a **cyclic reference**.

I use a bean for evicting this and with that the problem is that we have tried to use BeanUtils.copyProperty(dest, ori) in order to generate the bean response from the JPA Entity but the resulting response contains a list of EntityB objects instead of a list of BeanB response objects.

Is there any way or any library to generate the correct response bean?

**Note**: Using lazy is not an option because in some other methods I want to obtain the related entities.

Comment: Can you provide some code? How `Bean` wraps `Entity`? Is the **cyclic reference** due to generating `JSON` as response? Any stack trace to provide?

Comment: In less time that it would have taken to write this question, you could have manually produced the code transforming your entities into DTOs. That code would be super-simple, easy to write, read and understand, type-safe, faster than a refletion-based approach, resistant to refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the JSON serializier.

Often there is something like a **@JsonIgnore annotation** that you can use to break the cycles.